# How to change dojo content tab focus when closing a tab to focus on previous tab instead of first tab?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dojo, dijit.layout

I'm using `Dojo`'s `Dijit Layout` for generating content tab-panes similar to `Dijit` [Theme Tester Demo](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/themeTester.html). All of the tabs here are closeable.

The issue is: when I close a tab it goes back to the first tab in the list instead of the previous tab (available next to it).

You can think of it like opening a new tab in Firefox or Chrome and try closing the last tab.... on closing tab, it changes the focus to the previous tab which is a predictable behavior for working with tabs. But with `dijit.TabContainer`s, by default it goes back to the very first tab instead of previous one. This is a serious flaw when you consider the UI basics.

I have checked with `dojo` docs, but don't found any hint on this. Any idea how to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so when the [X] button on the **dijit.layout.ContentPane** (tab) is clicked an event **onClose** is generated, the **dijit.layout.TabContainer** is listening to this event, so when this happens, it executes the callback **closeChild()** then the function ***removeChild()*** is executed, this last one is the one you should override.

The tabContainer inherits this two functions from **dijit.layout.StackContainer** you should check the API documentation.

So for being able to modify the default behavior of the closing tabs, you should override the default functionality, in the example below i do this. Read the comments for info on where to add your logic.

E.g.

```
<script>
    require([
        "dojo/parser",

        "dojo/_base/lang", //this is the one that has the extend function
        "dojo/topic", //this is needed inside the overrided function

        "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 

        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Parser, lang, topic, tabContainer, contentPane){
        Parser.parse();

        // this will extend the tabContainer class and we will override the method in question
        lang.extend(tabContainer, {

            // this function, i copied it from the dijit.layout.StackContainer class
            removeChild: function(/*dijit._Widget*/ page){

                // for this to work i had to add as first argument the string "startup"
                this.inherited("startup", arguments);

                if(this._started){
                    // also had to call the dojo.topic class in the require statement
                    topic.publish(this.id + "-removeChild", page);  
                }

                if(this._descendantsBeingDestroyed){ return; }

                if(this.selectedChildWidget === page){
                    this.selectedChildWidget = undefined;
                    if(this._started){
                        var children = this.getChildren();
                        if(children.length){

                            // this is what you want to add your logic
                            // the var children (array) contains a list of all the tabs
                            // the index selects the tab starting from left to right 
                            // left most being the 0 index   

                            this.selectChild(children[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(this._started){
                    this.layout();
                }
            }
        });

        // now you can use your modified tabContainer WALAAAAAAA!
        // from here on, normal programmatic tab creation
        var tc = new tabContainer({
            style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;",
        }, "tab-container-div-id");

        var cp1 = new contentPane({
            title: "First Tab",
            closable: true
        });
        tc.addChild(cp1);

        var cp2 = new contentPane({
            title: "Second Tab",
            closable: true
        });
        tc.addChild(cp2);

        var cp3 = new contentPane({
            title: "Third Tab",
            selected: true,
            closable: true
        });
        tc.addChild(cp3);

        tc.startup();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dojo 1.10, reverting to the previous tab is the normal behaviour for TabContainers (instead of reverting to the first tab).

Presumably, you could use `dojo/aspect` to get the old behaviour (warning: not tested):

```
require( [ 'dijit/registry', 'dojo/aspect', 'dojo/_base/lang' ],
    function( registry, aspect, lang )
    {
        var tabContainer = registry.byId( 'tab_container');
        aspect.before( tabContainer, 'removeChild', lang.hitch( tabContainer, function( page )
        {
            if(this.selectedChildWidget === page)
            {
                this.selectedChildWidget = undefined;
                if(this._started)
                {
                    var children = this.getChildren();
                    this.selectChild( children[0] );
                }
            }

            return page;
        } ) );
    }
);
```

Or, alternatively, you could use the `onClose` extension point on a tab's `ContentPane`:

```
require( [ 'dijit/registry', 'dojo/_base/lang' ],
    function( registry, lang ) {
        newTabPane.onClose = lang.hitch(this, function () {
            // select first
            var tabContainer = registry.byId('tab_container'),
                all_tabs = tabContainer.getChildren();
            tabContainer.selectChild( all_tabs[0] );

            // allow save to go ahead
            return true;
        });
    }
);
```

Obviously, both these approaches would allow you to select a specific different pane on a tab being closed instead with a little tweaking...